# iText7 / iText7.pdfhtml - generating accessible tagged PDF from HTML results in incorrect tab order

Tags: pdf, itext, accessibility, tagging

Here's an HTML snippet:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Calibri,Arial,Tahoma,Helvetica,sans-serif;
            color: black;
            font-size: 12pt;
            width: 595pt;
        }

        h1 {
            color: #553c74;
            font-size: 18pt;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

            h1.title {
                display: inline;
                font-size: 28pt;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #553c74;
            }

        h2 {
            color: #553c74;
            font-size: 16pt;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        h3 {
            color: #00759b;
            font-size: 12pt;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

            h3.requiredAction {
                color: black;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin-top: 21px;
            }

        .headingLeft {
            float: left;
        }

        .contentRight {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-top: 17px;
        }

        .topSection {
            margin-top: 22px;
        }

        .clearBoth {
            clear: both;
        }

        .symbolstandardmet {
            color: #009639;
            font-family: webdings;
            font-size: 18pt;
        }

        .standardmet {
            color: #009639;
        }

        .standard {
            font-size: 16pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .pageBreakBefore {
            margin-top: 0px;
        }

        .premisesAddress {
            font-size: 18pt;
            color: #553c74;
            line-height: 0px;
        }

        .pageBreakBefore {
            page-break-before: always;
        }

        #contentWrapperBody {
            padding-left: 8pt;
            padding-right: 45pt;
        }

        h1 {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        @page:first {
            margin-top: 170pt;
        }
    </style>

    <title>Report</title>

</head>
<body id="contentWrapperBody">
    <h1>Name:</h1>
    <span id="lblAddress" class="premisesAddress">Address Line 1, Address line 2, City, Postcode</span>

    <div class="clearBoth"></div>

    <h2 class="headingLeft">Reference:</h2>
    <div class="contentRight topSection">123456789</div>

    <div class="clearBoth"></div>

    <h2 class="headingLeft">Type:</h2>
    <div class="contentRight topSection">The type</div>

    <div class="clearBoth"></div>

    <h2 class="headingLeft">Date:</h2>
    <div class="contentRight topSection">12/04/2019</div>

    <div class="clearBoth"></div>

    <h2>Context</h2>
    <div>
        <p>A paragraph of context info here.</p>
    </div>


    <h2>Overall outcome</h2>
    <h3>
        <span id="lblOverallStandardsMet" class="standardmet"><span class="symbolstandardmet">a</span>Standards met</span>
    </h3>


    <h3 class="headingLeft requiredAction">Required Action:</h3>
    <div class="contentRight topSection"><span id="lblRequiredAction">None</span></div>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
    <p>Follow this link to <a href="#tbldefinitions">find out what the possible outcomes mean</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the code:

```
 public static class DocConverter
{
    private const string fontWebdings = "~/content/fonts/webdings.ttf";
    private const string fontCalibri = "~/content/fonts/calibrib.ttf";

    [Flags]
    public enum DocOptions
    {
        None = 0,
        DisplayTitle = 1,
        AddHeaderPageOne = 2,
        AddHeaderAllPages = 4,
        AddLineBottomEachPage = 8
    }

    public static byte[] ConvertToPdfWithTags(string html, string title, string docOptions)
    {
        DocOptions documentOptions = DocOptions.None;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(docOptions))
        {
            int options;
            if (int.TryParse(docOptions, out options))
                documentOptions = (DocOptions)options;
        }

        PdfFontFactory.RegisterDirectory(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/content/fonts/"));
        ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();


        FontProvider fp = new FontProvider();

        fp.AddDirectory(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/content/fonts/"));

        props.SetFontProvider(fp);
        props.SetTagWorkerFactory(new DefaultTagWorkerFactory());

        using (var workStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(workStream, new WriterProperties().AddUAXmpMetadata().SetPdfVersion
                (PdfVersion.PDF_2_0).SetFullCompressionMode(true)))
            {

                PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
                pdfDoc.GetCatalog().SetLang(new PdfString("en-GB"));


                pdfDoc.GetCatalog().SetViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().SetDisplayDocTitle(true));
        //This event handler used for adding background images.  Also where I've tried setting the tab order on pdfPage
                //if (documentOptions > 0)
                //    pdfDoc.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new PublicReportHeaderFooter(documentOptions, title));
                //Set meta tags
                var pdfMetaData = pdfDoc.GetDocumentInfo();
                pdfMetaData.AddCreationDate();
                pdfMetaData.GetProducer();
                pdfMetaData.SetCreator("iText Software");
                //Set the document to be tagged
                pdfDoc.SetTagged();

                using (var document = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(html, pdfDoc, props))
                {
                    //Can do more with document here if necessary


                }

                //Returns the written-to MemoryStream containing the PDF.   
                return workStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }



}
```

If I open up the resulting PDF in Acrobat Pro and do an accessibility report and check the reading order, it jumps from the name on the first line, to the context much further down, rather than being in top-bottom, left-right order :
[image: screenshot from acrobat]

It appears to be due to the "float: left" style on some of the elements, but I'm not sure how to get around it.  I've tried playing with page.Put(PdfName.Tag, PdfName.S) and page.SetTabOrder(PdfName.S), putting in different parameters (C or R, for example), but these appear to make no difference. I'm using C# iText7 version 7.1.9 and iText7.pdfhtml version 2.1.6.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The more I look at the documentation, the more I think this is just a bug.  The reading order in the accessible PDF should match the structural order of the HTML document by default, but the **float: left** styles seem to throw things out.  I can't find a way to raise a bug in GitHub for this project, but I've found a workaround for anyone else with the issue, which is simply to add "float: left" to all other elements as necessary, along with

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

between the elements that don't actually need the float. This way the accessible tagged order comes out correctly.  However, this did throw up another problem which was that the elements with "float: left" no longer appeared on a new page where "page-break-before: always" was also set. I had to add another empty div element before these elements with the page-break-before style set to fix this. Hopefully the iText people will see this and either fix these issues, if they're bugs, or respond with a better answer if I've just got things wrong.

Comment: hi! I'm an "iText people", so I will follow-up